# Cannot install Python 3.4.5 on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

I already have python 3.5 installed on my computer. But I need to install python 3.4.5 on my computer in order to use lxml. I tried to install by running setup.py file in the download folder as below:

```
C:\Users\Juan\Downloads\Python-3.4.5>setup.py
```

But got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan\Downloads\Python-3.4.5\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'] = cflags + ' ' + py_cflags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I have no clue what is the issue. Do I need to uninstall py 3.5 first? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well First, You should uninstall python 3.5, and Im pretty sure there is an exe you have to use to install, if I am correct.

Comment: @UnkownEscapist: Actually, "Python 3.4.5 has only been released in source code form; no more official binary installers will be produced." - [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-345/) When trying to install from the source, I am getting the same error as the OP. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use lxml on win on py3.5:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Carefully select:
lxml‑3.6.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl or lxml‑3.6.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl, depending on your OS and then run:

```
pip install c:/lxml‑3.6.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Just change path accordingly. You might also encounter other compiler problems, so you might need this: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
There was Q&A's for this, but I can't find them, so just install this.